# How to compare the current time with other existing 4 time fields

Tags: mysql

I am having a table with 4 timings as bus_start_time1, bus_end_time1, start_time_2 and end_time2.
Now my requirement is to build a query that falls between start_time1 and end_time1 or start_time2 and end_time2 when compared with current time.

This is my table:

```
+------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+-----------+
| vendor_id  | start_time1 | end_time1 | start_time2 | end_time2 |
+------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+-----------+
| 5000788324 | 09:00 AM    | 11:00 AM  | 02:00 PM    | 06:00 PM  | 
| 5000815782 | 10:00 AM    | 01:00 PM  | 02:00 PM    | 10:00 PM  | 
| 5000482136 | 09:00 AM    | 01:00 PM  | 02:00 PM    | 09:00 PM  | 
| 6786788131 | 09:00 AM    | 11:00 AM  | 02:00 PM    | 06:00 PM  | 
+------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+-----------+
```

I tried the following query but it didn't work for me:

```
select count(ven_availability_id) as count from vendor_del_avilability vda where vda.vendor_id = ? and ((vda.bus_start_time1 >  DATE_FORMAT(now(), '%T')  and vda.bus_end_time1 >  DATE_FORMAT(now(), '%T')) or  (vda.bus_start_time2 >  DATE_FORMAT(now(), '%T')  and vda.bus_end_time2 >  DATE_FORMAT(now(), '%T')));
```

Please help me out. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What have you tied so far? `SELECT ... FROM ... WHERE .... AND ...;`!?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT count(vendor_id) as count
FROM vendor_del_avilability
WHERE vendor_id = ?
AND (
    NOW() BETWEEN
    (STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(CURDATE(), ' ', start_time1), '%Y-%m-%d %h:%i%p'))
    AND 
    (STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(CURDATE(), ' ', end_time1), '%Y-%m-%d %h:%i%p'))
)
OR
(
    NOW() BETWEEN
    (STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(CURDATE(), ' ', start_time2), '%Y-%m-%d %h:%i%p')) 
    AND
    (STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(CURDATE(), ' ', end_time2), '%Y-%m-%d %h:%i%p'))
);
```

Answer (score 0):

What about between:

```
select f_name, l_name, age from
    -> employee_data where age BETWEEN
    -> 32 AND 40;
```

Theoretically without the date portion, it should just see 1 jan 1900, so all's fair.

Answer (score 0):

I think, this is what you require :

```
   select count(*)
   from vendor_del_availability
   where (CURTIME() BETWEEN start_time1 AND end_time1) 
   or (CURTIME() BETWEEN start_time2 AND end_time2);
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your values are stored as `time` values, you can do:

```
where vda.vendor_id = ? and
      ((vda.bus_start_time1 < time(now())  and
        vda.bus_end_time1 > time(now())
       ) or
       (vda.bus_start_time2 < time(now())  and
        vda.bus_end_time2 > time(now())
       )
      )
```

If they are stored as strings, then use `str_to_date()` to convert them to `time`.  You cannot do string comparisons on times that contain `AM` and `PM`.

Note that your original query has the logic backwards for the start time.

Comment: thanks for the idea @Gordon Linoff. I changed to str_to_date(), it's work for me :)